# Pass data to View Controller embedded inside a Container View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

My view controller hierarchy is the following:

[image: view controller hierarchy]

- The entry point is a `UINavigationController`, whose root view controller is a usual `UITableViewController`. The Table View presents a list of letters.
- When the user taps on a cell, a *push segue* is triggered, and the view transitions to `ContainerViewController`. It contains an embedded `ContentViewController`, whose role is to present the selected letter on screen.

The Content View Controller stores the letter to be shown as a property `letter: String`, which should be set before its view is pushed on screen.

```swift
class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    var letter = "-"
    @IBOutlet private weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        label.text = letter
    }
}
```

On the contrary, the Container View Controller should not know anything about the letter (content-unaware), since I'm trying to build it as reusable as possible.

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var contentViewController: ContentViewController? {
        return childViewControllers.first as? ContentViewController
    }
}
```

I tried to write `prepareForSegue()` in my Table View Controller accordingly :

```swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ContainerViewController {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        let letter = letterForIndexPath(indexPath)
        containerViewController.navigationItem.title = "Introducing \(letter)"
        // Not executed:
        containerViewController.contentViewController?.letter = letter
    }
}
```

but **`contentViewController` is not yet created by the time this method is called**, and the letter property is never set.

It is worth mentioning that this does work when the segue's destination view controller is set directly on the Content View Controller -- after updating `prepareForSegue()` accordingly.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: "The Container view controller should not know anything about the letter" seems like an odd requirement. The user saw a table view, they tapped a row, another view controller was presented... of course it should be aware of that data. It sounds like you're looking for a solution in search of a real problem.

Comment: Mmmm... I disagree in that one. The aim of a container view controller is (can ?) be to alter the way its child view controllers are presented, and not about formatting and passing around the data itself. Take `UISplitViewController` as an example: it should not know anything about what data is presented -- similarly for a `UIPageViewController` or a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Or I'm missing something big here... In that case I'd be very grateful for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I feel like the correct solution is to rely on **programmatic instantiation of the content view**, and this is what I chose after careful and thorough thoughts.

Here are the steps that I followed:

- The Table View Controller has a push segue set to `ContainerViewController` in the storyboard. It still gets performed when the user taps on a cell.
- I removed the embed segue from the Container View to the `ContentViewController` in the storyboard, and I added an IB Outlet to that Container View in my class.
- I set a storyboard ID to the Content View Controller, say… `ContentViewController`, so that we can instantiate it programmatically in due time.
- I implemented a custom Container View Controller, as described in Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1). Now my `ContainerViewController.swift` looks like (most of the code install and removes the layout constraints):

  ```
  class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

      var contentViewController: UIViewController? {
          willSet {
              setContentViewController(newValue)
          }
      }


      @IBOutlet private weak var containerView: UIView!
      private var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()


      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          setContentViewController(contentViewController)
      }

      private func setContentViewController(newContentViewController: UIViewController?) {
          guard isViewLoaded() else { return }
          if let previousContentViewController = contentViewController {
              previousContentViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
              containerView.removeConstraints(constraints)
              previousContentViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
              previousContentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
          }
          if let newContentViewController = newContentViewController {
              let newView = newContentViewController.view
              addChildViewController(newContentViewController)
              containerView.addSubview(newView)
              newView.frame = containerView.bounds
              constraints.append(newView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.leadingAnchor))
              constraints.append(newView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.topAnchor))
              constraints.append(newView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.trailingAnchor))
              constraints.append(newView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.bottomAnchor))
              constraints.forEach { $0.active = true }
              newContentViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
          }
      } }
  ```
- In my `LetterTableViewController` class, I instantiate and setup my Content View Controller, which is added to the Container's child view controllers. Here is the code:

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if let containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ContainerViewController {
          let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
          let letter = letterForIndexPath(indexPath)
          containerViewController.navigationItem.title = "Introducing \(letter)"
          if let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController"),
             let contentViewController = viewController as? ContentViewController {
              contentViewController.letter = letter
              containerViewController.contentViewController = contentViewController
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This works perfectly, with an entirely content-agnostic container view controller. By the way, it used to be the way one instantiated a `UITabBarController` or a `UINavigationController` along with its children, in the `appDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` delegate method.

The only downside of this I can see: the UI flow ne longer appears explicitly on the [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS5Lu.png).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to add delegation so that your tableViewController implements a protocol with one method to return the letter; then you have containerViewController setting its childViewController (the contentViewController) delegate to its parent. And the contentViewController can finally ask its delegate for the letter.

Answer (score 0):

At your current solution the presenting object itself is responsible for working both with the "container" and the "content", it doesn't *have to* be changed, but such solution not only has the issues like the one you described, but also makes the purpose of the "container" not very clear.

Look at the `UIAlertController`: you are not configuring its child view controller directly, you are not even supposed to know it exists when using the alert controller. Instead of configuring the "content", you are configuring the "container" which is aware of the content interfaces, lifecycle and behavior and doesn't expose it. Following this approach you achieve a properly divided responsibility of the container and content, minimal exposure of the "content" allows you to update the "container" without a need to update the way it is used.

In short, instead of trying to configure everything from a single place, make it so you configure only the "container" and let it configure the "content" when and where it is needed. E.g. in the scenario you described the "container" would set data for the "content" whenever it initializes the child controllers. I'm using "container" and "content" instead of `ContainerViewController` and `ContentViewController` because the solution is not strictly based on the controllers because you might as well replace it wth `NSObject` + `UIView` or `UIWindow`.

Comment: I got your point, and I see what you mean in the case of `UIAlertController`. But in some cases, I feel like the container should really be content-unaware, just like `UITabController` or `UINavigationController` are. By the way, when one uses segues to transition to a View Controller embedded in a `UINavigationController`, how can one configure this View Controller in `prepareForSegue()`?

Comment: You are confusing two different scenarios: pushing a new VC through a segue and pushing a new navigation controller with a stack of new "content" view controllers. The former is a normal use case and you are able to quickly configure the destination-view-controller, the latter is similar to your original question and is not as straightforward since you yourself have opted to a  lazy "content" view controllers initialization. There are different approaches to how such lazily initialized objects are configured and the choice of how to do it is what makes the architecture of your app.

Comment: As for how to make the "container" unaware of the "content", consider the following options: 1) initialize and fully configure the "content" view controllers yourself as a part of "container" initialization and configuration 2) delegate content initialization or content setup either through protocols or public interfaces. Delegates are more versatile; public interfaces with weak references seemingly provide the easiest solution, but will often produce spaghetti code if used in this way; full initialization can be expansive (or even worse, become later when it is hard to update).

Comment: Alright, I was not confusing the two situations, I just pointed out the similarities between pushing a Navigation View Controller and setting up its root view controller, and the situation described in the question. And in both cases 1) and 2), the container is somehow aware of its child content, either by holding and forwarding the data, or by holding a pointer to the child's delegate, which conforms to a child-specific protocol -- in both cases the container is not reusable. Anyway, I used the first solution, and made the `ContainerViewController` setup the `ContentViewController`.